# How to specify constant inputs for Gradio click handler?

Tags: python, gradio

If I have the following code:

```py
submit = gr.Button(...)
submit.click(
  fn=my_func,
  inputs=[
    some_slider_1, # gr.Slider
    some_slider_2, # gr.Slider
    some_slider_3, # gr.Slider
  ],
  outputs=[ some_text_field ]
)
```

How can I substitute let's say `some_slider_2` for a constant value like 2?
If I simply write `2` in there, I get an error:
`AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute '_id'`

Comment: Do you want a constant number input which is not visible on the UI?

Comment: Yes, best if it doesn't create any UI element at all, although after some consideration I could maybe just have it as a global variable instead of passing it through the inputs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a constant number input which is not visible on the UI you can pass `gr.Number(value=2, visible=False)`